# Insert a column of non-numeric data into a cell's column at arbitrary location and shift old data to the right

Tags: matlab, insert, cell, shift

I need to insert a column (vector) with non-numeric data cells (one or multiple strings) into a cell of non-numeric data at an arbitrary location and retain old data columns by shifting them to the right.

my_word =

```
's'    'i'    'p'
's'    'i'    'p'
's'    'i'    'p'
's'    'i'    'p'
's'    'i'    'p'
```

my_column =

```
'a'
'b'
'c'
'd'
'e'
```

result_cell_1 =

```
's'    'a'    'i'    'p'
's'    'b'    'i'    'p'
's'    'c'    'i'    'p'
's'    'd'    'i'    'p'
's'    'e'    'i'    'p'
```

result_cell_2 =

```
's'    'i'    'a'    'p'
's'    'i'    'b'    'p'
's'    'i'    'c'    'p'
's'    'i'    'd'    'p'
's'    'i'    'e'    'p'
```

The major problem is that I want to insert a column at the second and the third location. In addition, I am not limited to the length in the example, so the solution should allow me to loop over a row of any length and insert a column at each location incrementally. Also, I have a solution for substitution each column, including the first and the last one, so they are not the problem. The problem is in the middle, where the length is not always the same.

Comment: Do you really want the results to be called `result_cell_1`? Variable names like this are usually hard to work with. A cell array would probably be better, `result_cell{1}=...`.

Comment: name is not important

Comment: Also, you'll need to explain this better "the solution should allow me to loop over a row of any length and insert a column at each location incrementally" and why your existing code (which you should also include) can't do this.

Comment: @David is right to encourage you to provide more details about what you've tried. It makes it much easier to get a helpful answer, and more useful for anyone who finds the question later.

Comment: I am just trying to say that the solution should not be for inserting a column into a n by 4 cell, but for n by m. As for the code, it merely replaces one column with another without shifting.

Comment: @David and kmac if this was an easy task, I would not have posted it here. I spent some time on trying to solve it at no avail.

Comment: @hike, posting the code that you tried (even if it doesn't work) shows that you put in effort, and also guides those answering to the specific place you're having trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manipulating cell arrays is very similar to normal matrices. If `i` were the column to insert,

```
result = [my_word(:,1:i-1) my_column my_word(:,i:end)]
```

would accomplish your goal. It breaks `my_word` into the first and second half, and concatenates them back together with `my_column` in the middle.

Comment: @David, he wants to insert a column, so slice through all the rows `(:,cols)`.

Comment: Works! Thank you @kmac !