# Concatenate a cell array into the middle of another cell array in Matlab

Tags: matlab, cell

I have two cell arrays, `cellarray1` (m x n) and `cellarray2` (m x 1), and want to take `cellarray2` and input this in `cellarray1`. However, I would like to input this in the second column, thus pushing the existing cells in `cellarray1` to the right, so that the final result is a cell array with n+1 columns with the new column having pushed all columns to the right, taking place at column 2 in `cellarray1`. Maybe this is a strange problem, I don't know. There is no straight forward solution as I have found.

Best,
Granit

Comment: so, you want to *insert* a column in an arbitrary column position?

Comment: Found this page. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33863776/insert-a-column-of-non-numeric-data-into-a-cells-column-at-arbitrary-location-a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [combine cell arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/combine-cell-arrays.html) using array concatenation operator, `[]`.

Let's say `cellarray1` is an M x N cell array and `cellarray2` is M x P. (In your example `P = 1`.) You can make the result you want in this way:

```
cellarray1 = [cellarray1(:,1), cellarray2, cellarray1(:,2:end)];
```

`cellarray2` is inserted in the 2nd till P+1th column of the output.